# Error when use FragmentContainerView and NavHostFragment

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack

This is my code in xml,

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_auth_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_auth" />
```

And I have Exception

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in activity_auth: Binary XML file line #9 in activity_auth: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in activity_auth: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentContainerView must have an android:id to add Fragment androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
```

Help me please, and thank!

Comment: There are no errors in the layout.. meanwhile you can use the latestet navigation arch dependeices and also we need to see the nav graph .. or you can share an example to reproduce the issue

Comment: @Zain I updated full log errror

Comment: Can you show the behavior how you instantiate the `NavHostFragment` ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Thanks